# Unordeded list float right collapses

Tags: html, css

Ok, consider the following [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/4gfjrLss/)

I want to float an unordered `<ul`> list right. If I don't specify a width, as in the fiddle, then a certain amount of `<li>`s will be on the same line, until one will jump to the next line.

If I give the `<ul>` a width, as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kh4xx34w/1/), you can see that the `<ul>` jumps back "leftwards". I want to be able to set the `<ul>` width as high as 100% of the encompassing `<div>` while still having the line items `<li>`s "right" floated.

```
<div>
    <ul>        
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>      
</div>

ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case it is easier to inline the list.

```css
div {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  color: white;
  font: 14px/1.6 sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Forgot about using inline-block by itself without the float!!!! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:left` on the `li` and don't use percentage padding.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gfjrLss/1/)

```
ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    padding-right: 1em;
}
```